# problemas para sumar en phpexcel

Tags: php, excel

En una consulta necesito sumar todos los valores que hay dentro una columna en phpexcel, el caso es que esos valores son llamados de la base de datos por lo que estan en un arreglo y no puedo lograrlo.

```html
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['cod_rep']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['fec_reg']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['tip_doc']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['num_doc']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $row['periodo']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $row['cat_reg']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $row['sub_cat_reg']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['actividad']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $row['cliente']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $row['cantidad']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $row['detalle']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $row['tip_ing']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$fila, $row['ingreso']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N'.$fila, $row['tip_eg']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O'.$fila, $row['egreso']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P'.$fila, $row['tip_det']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q'.$fila, $row['detraccion']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R'.$fila, $row['sal_ini']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S'.$fila, $row['efec_dol']);

 
  $fila++;

 } 
 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion, "A7:S".$fila);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, 'Totales');
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->mergeCells('A'.($fila).':L'.($fila));
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$fila, '=SUM(M7:M)'.$fila);
```

Ejecute el calculo puesto que al descargar el archivo me sale un mensaje de que el documento esta dañado.

Answer (score 0):

parece que tienes varios errores de sintaxis, debiera quedar como sigue:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A', "$fila", "$row[cod_rep]");
```

presta atención al uso de la doble comilla y los separadores por coma